# Flutter how to set container on other container with stack

Tags: flutter

I have simple 2 widget is Stack i need to show the second widget on the end of first widget

Some thing like this

[image]

Here is my code

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight * 0.8),
            height: height * 0.4,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  'assets/images/place2.jpg',
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30), topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.03,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: height * 0.01,
                      width: width * 0.1,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.031,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: width,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        'PLACES',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: height * 0.02,
                    ),
                    Places(),
                    Places(),
                    Places(),
                    Places(),
                    Places(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )



        ],
      ),
```

In this code the second widget overlaps with first widget and cover the whole screen. I just need to show it and the end of first widget

Answer (score 0):

The widget you are looking for is `Positioned`.

You use it like

```dart
Stack(
   children: [
       //Behind container, fill screen (can also use Positioned.fill)
       Positioned(top:0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, child: Container()), 

       //Front most container, aligned bottom, full width
       Positioned(left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, child: Container()), 
   ]
)
```

Comment: Try this also but issue is height dont know why height is just fixed when i give the Top value its just changing in that height only

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem make sure everything is wrapped in a positioned and use the second positioned example on the bottom widget. Then set the column property to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` (i think thats it.) Right now the column will fill the space, min shrinkwraps it to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing correctly but because of Column widget size you are got getting your desire output.

You can give mainAxisSize to  MainAxisSize.min, so it will only take space which that widget require.

```
 child: Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,   // added line
       children: <Widget>[
```

if Your widget size if big and then also you want same behaviour then you can **give height to container** and wrap column with **SingleChildScrollView**.

Comment: add this line also try to give height to the container and wrap the column with SingleChildScrollView still not working the Align widget is still on top of the first widget

Comment: height is should be how much length you want in blow section. try height=250, so you will get idea.

Comment: I add the height but seems like its not increasing just stick on first widget and show the error when i increase the height

Comment: try this widget. DraggableScrollableSheet

Answer (score 0):

```
 Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 200,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text("Text"),
      ),
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                topRight: Radius.circular(35))),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

> setting the MainAxisAlignment of Column to MainAxisAlignment.end pushed the container at bottom and gave me the results i wanted.